# Detect tab close and clear local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

In order to clear local storage I use something like this:

```
localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

but I would like clear storage when detect that the tab was closed. How can I make it?

Comment: Would `sessionStorage` not be more suited to your needs if you only want the data available for the current browser session?

Answer (score 2):

When a tab (window) is closed, your code can process the `unload` event.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
};
```

**However**, if you're doing something session-specific, you probably want to store it in session storage (`sessionStorage`) rather than local storage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
};
```

But as Rory already mentioned, it would be better if you use `sessionStorage` for your needs.